# DRF: how to change the value of the model fields before saving to the database

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I need to change some field values before saving to the database as I think models method `clear()` is suitable.  But I can't call him despite all my efforts.

For example fields **email** I need set to *lowercase* and fields **nda** I need set as `null`

**models.py**

```
class Vendors(models.Model):

    nda = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    parent = models.OneToOneField('Vendors', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.nda == "":
            self.nda = None

class VendorContacts(models.Model):
    ....
    vendor = models.ForeignKey('Vendors', related_name='contacts', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)

    def clean(self):
        if self.email:
            self.email = self.email.lower()
```

**serializer.py**

```
class VendorContactSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = VendorContacts
        fields = (
                  ...
                  'email',)

class VendorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contacts = VendorContactSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Vendors
        fields = (...
                  'nda',
                  'contacts',
                  )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        contact_data = validated_data.pop('contacts')
        vendor = Vendors.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for data in contact_data:
            VendorContacts.objects.create(vendor=vendor, **data)

        return vendor
```

**views.py**

```
class VendorsCreateView(APIView):
    """Create new vendor instances from form"""
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = VendorsSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = VendorsSerializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
        except ValidationError:
            return Response({"errors": (serializer.errors,)},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(request.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

As I learned from the  documentation

> Django Rest Framework serializers do not call the Model.clean when
>   validating model serializers

In dealing with this problem, I found two ways to solve it.
1. using the custom method at serializer. For my case, it looks like

class VendorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contacts = VendorContactSerializer(many=True)

```
class Meta:
    model = Vendors
    fields = (...
              'nda',
              'contacts',
              )

def create(self, validated_data):
    contact_data = validated_data.pop('contacts')
    vendor = Vendors.objects.create(**validated_data)
    for data in contact_data:
        VendorContacts.objects.create(vendor=vendor, **data)

    return vendor

def validate(self, attrs):
    instance = Vendors(**attrs)
    instance.clean()
    return attrs
```

2. Using `full_clean()` method. For me, it looks like

class VendorsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contacts = VendorContactSerializer(many=True)

```
class Meta:
    model = Vendors
    fields = (...
              'nda',
              'contacts',
              )

def create(self, validated_data):
    contact_data = validated_data.pop('contacts')
    vendor = Vendors(**validated_data)
    vendor.full_clean()
    vendor.save()
    for data in contact_data:
        VendorContacts.objects.create(vendor=vendor, **data)

    return vendor
```

But in both cases, the clean() method is not called. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For DRF you can change your serializer before save as below...

First of all, you should check that `serializer` is valid or not, and if it is `valid` then change the required object of the `serializer` and then save that `serializer`.

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.object.user_id = 15  # For example 
    serializer.save()
```

UPD!
**views.py**

```
class VendorsCreateView(APIView):
    """Create new vendor instances from form"""
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = VendorsSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = request.data
        if data['nda'] == '':
            data['nda'] = None
        for contact in data['contacts']:
            if contact['email']:
                print(contact['email'])
                contact['email'] = contact['email'].lower()
        serializer = VendorsSerializer(data=request.data)
        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
        except ValidationError:
            return Response({"errors": (serializer.errors,)},
                            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: In my case, the serializer is not valid. If I don't transmit the date field as blank, I get the `Date has the wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD`. Correspondingly, the code will not go further than `serializer.is_valid()`.

Comment: Then you have to make your `serializer` valid with appropriate changes and then use the above method to change the value of `serializer` object before `save`

Comment: But that's the question how to make the serializer valid if an empty value of the DataField field causes an error.

Comment: Then, first of all, change the date with `serializer.object.date_field = required date` and then after check it that is it valid or not.

Comment: That's an interesting idea. I'll try it now.

Comment: Perfect! This is not quite an answer to the question why the `clean()` method is not called, but it works exactly as I need it to.

Comment: Great, Happy Coding :)

Comment: It's better to handle it with serializer methods, view is not a good place for that.In Django structures all validation and other actions on data must be handled in serializers

Answer (score 5):

In my case I had the same problem but with validation feature
I used the way below and it works for me (not excludes the way found above):

```
class CustomViewClass(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        
        prepared_data_variable = 'some data in needed format'
        serializer = CustomSerializer(data=request.data)
    
        if serializer.is_valid(self):
            serializer.validated_data['field_name'] = prepared_data_variable
            serializer.save()
            return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This string is key for my solution **serializer.validated_data['field_name'] = prepared_data_variable**

Comment: In my case, the serializer is not valid. Еhe code will not go further than `serializer.is_valid()`. We discussed ways to address Michael's response in his comments on

Comment: Absolutely agree with you, I just tried to solve a similar problem and I got the solution. Maybe my idea can extend your solution I thought. Only Mike's solution gave me the food for the brain.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: just override `save()` method for your models [as written in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods). There you can assign any values to your model instance directly before saving it in database.

Also, you should probably use `models.EmailField` for your email fields which will get rid of your lower() check.

Comment: I think its more suitable for pure Django not for DRF

Comment: The save method will not be called because the data will not be validated.

Comment: Ok, got it. You could either:
1. pass null instead of empty string to endpoint
2. Override data at your view, before passing it to serializer
3. Setup `to_internal_value(self, data)` method in your serializer

In the last case - it should do smth like this: `if not data['date']: data['date'] = None; return data`
[docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer)

Comment: 1. if you mean don't pass on `nda` at all, then yes, it will work. 2. the most appropriate way I think. 3. It should work, but it's harder than the second way.